# Confusion about classes

Tags: oop

I am quite new to OOP concepts and I'm trying to create a food delivery system system, and I have different users(admin,clerks,officers) that access the system

I have customers that will be registered into the system and orders that will be placed for the customers.

Therefore I have created methods for registering customers(registerCustomer) and placing orders(placeOrder) alongside other methods. Now I am quite confused which classes these methods will go under. Should the registerCustomer go under my User class(which different users inherit from) or Customer class. Same thing about the order placement. Should I create an order class or will placeOrder go under Customer or User class

Comment: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a lot of ways you could do this, and many books and online resources that can teach you about object oriented programming. In general, you want to place your methods in classes that those methods operate on, and not in classes that can't be affected by those methods. So, if only `Customers` can be registered, and `Clerks` and `Officers` cannot, then the `registerCustomer()` method should be accessible only from the `Customer` class and not the `User` class it inherits from. Similarly, if only a `Customer` can place an `Order` then that's where the `placeOrder()` method should be located.

However, you should also consider what other object participates in each operation. For instance, perhaps the `registerCustomer()` method really belongs in a `FoodDeliverySystem` class. For instance:

```
FoodDeliverySystem mySystem = new FoodDeliverySystem();
Customer myCustomer = new Customer();
Order myOrder = new Order();

mySystem.registerCustomer(myCustomer);
myCustomer.placeOrder(myOrder);
```